# Deleting Duplicate Records in Access Based on Multiple Fields While Retaining Lowest Priority

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in Microsoft Access with, among others, the fields (UN, PSN, Class, ClassAll, PG, priority). I need to delete duplicate records based on the fields (UN, PSN, Class, ClassAll, PG) but retain only the ones with the lowest priority value in field priority
I tried the following:

```
DELETE FROM tbl
WHERE (UN, PSN, Class, ClassAll, PG, priority) NOT IN (
    SELECT UN, PSN, Class, ClassAll, PG, MIN(priority) AS MinPriority
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY UN, PSN, Class, ClassAll, PG
);
```

However, this results in an error:
`Query must have at least one destination field`

Below a small example of the data.
the bold marked values are considered duplicates because the values are the same in the fields (UN, PSN, Class, ClassAll, PG)
In this example the records with IDs 6589 and 17 should be deleted and the one with the lowest priority value (ID 120) shall retain

**SAMPLE DATA**

| ID | UN | PSN | Class | classAll | PG | Priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | **1006** | **AUDI** | **2.2** | **2.2** | **A** | 1 |
| 2 | 1950 | VW | 2.1 | 2.2,8 | A | 11 |
| 3 | 1950 | VW | 2.1 | 2.2,6.1 | B | 10 |
| 4 | 1950 | VW | 2.1 | 2.2,6.1,8 | B | 12 |
| 6589 | **1006** | **AUDI** | **2.2** | **2.2** | **A** | 2 |
| 6 | 1950 | PEUGEOT | 2.2 | 2.2 | B | 18 |
| 17 | **1006** | **AUDI** | **2.2** | **2.2** | **A** | 9 |

**DESIRED OUTCOME**

| ID | UN | PSN | Class | classAll | PG | Priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | **1006** | **AUDI** | **2.2** | **2.2** | **A** | 1 |
| 2 | 1950 | VW | 2.1 | 2.2,8 | A | 11 |
| 3 | 1950 | VW | 2.1 | 2.2,6.1 | B | 10 |
| 4 | 1950 | VW | 2.1 | 2.2,6.1,8 | B | 12 |
| 6 | 1950 | PEUGEOT | 2.2 | 2.2 | B | 18 |

What would be the proper way to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```sql
DELETE * 
FROM tbl As T1
WHERE T1.priority NOT IN (
    SELECT Top 1 T2.priority
    FROM tbl As T2
    WHERE T1.UN = T2.UN And T1.PSN = T2.PSN And T1.Class = T2.Class And T1.ClassAll = T2.ClassAll
    ORDER BY Priority Asc);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Gustav but it is not returning the desired outcome. The result appear a bit random. not sure what is amiss

Comment: Not sure what random means in this context. Result matches the requested.

Comment: I see that it does not take field `PG` into consideration. that is why I got more results. However when I update your query with `And T1.PG = T2.PG` I get even more results that less. I would have expected way fever results

Comment: Problem appears to be with field `PG` which doe snot always have values. solved with `AND (T1.PG = T2.PG OR (T1.PG IS NULL AND T2.PG IS NULL))`